# Adding one row to UITableView with a data source

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` that loads certain data from a remote feed, and I want to manually add one row on top the table, at the beginning of all the rows loaded from the feed.

So for example, if from the feed I would have a table with the rows

//////////////////////////////////////////

1 (loaded from UITableView data source)

//////////////////////////////////////////

2 (loaded from UITableView data source)

//////////////////////////////////////////

3 (loaded from UITableView data source)

//////////////////////////////////////////

---

I would like to manually add one row on top of those, so I would have:

---

//////////////////////////////////////////

0 (manually added)

//////////////////////////////////////////

1 (loaded from UITableView data source)

//////////////////////////////////////////

2 (loaded from UITableView data source)

//////////////////////////////////////////

3 (loaded from UITableView data source)

//////////////////////////////////////////

Is this possible? Is there any other way of doing this in case it is not possible? Like having two `UITableView` and putting them together or something like that.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Do you want 1 row by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the new element to the array where you have the data, for example:

```
//This is your data:
NSMutableArray *myData;

//Add new row at the beggining:
[myData insertObject:newData atIndex:0];

//Reload your table view
[self.myTableView reloadData];
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's possible.
In the function where you want to add you row, do :

```
NSMutableArray *indexPathsToInsert = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[indexPathsToInsert addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];

[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathsToInsert withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

you can change the row insertion animation depending of what effect you want.
/!\ your data source and your function `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` must be consistent with what you want to display

Answer (score 0):

If it's static first row you want to add, I would suggest you use a UITableViewHeader to display it instead of UITableViewCell. If you do want to it to be a sell, why don't you add another section? The first section will contain just this one cell, and the second will contain all the cells displaying the data you get from the feed. You can skip the header view, so it will not be noticeable that you have 2 sections instead of one. 
Another way is of course to add the data you want to display in the first cell to your datasource and have just one section, but I like the first approach better, because there the code and logic is cleaner

Answer (score 0):

You must be using array to load the data from remote in your table view.
Just push a element(whatever data you need in first row) in beginning of those arrays.

Insert an element in the beginning of array as:

```
NSMutableArray* array;
[array insertObject:dataInFirstRow atIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 0):

It may useful to you..

1) Insert first that new element into your datasource array.

2) Get visible row indexPath by

```
NSArray *visibleIndexes = [self.tableview indexPathsForVisibleRows];
```

3) Then reload all visible rows without animation :

```
[self.tableview reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:visibleIndexes withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone]
```